# How to model a Predicate w/ BooleanBuilder (QueryDSL) an optional OnetoOne JPA/Hibernate relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, predicate

I am trying to build a boolean predicate for an Entity relationship that follows:

There is a table of Employees, and some of these Employees may be a Manager.

Employee.java:

```java
private int empId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPID", referencedColumnName = "MANAGER_EMPID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)  //Not everyone is a manager
private Manager manager;
```

Then I want to return only those employees that are Managers.

I have attempted:

```java
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
QEmployee qEmployee = QEmployee.employee;

builder.and(qEmployee.manager.isNotNull());
// as well as:
// builder.and(qEmployee.manager.managerId.isNotNull());
```

Neither is working as neither attempt ends up modifying the JPA/Hibernate queries that are being used.

How can I use QuerySQL and BooleanBuilder to return only those employees that are Managers?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you a clear understanding. Look here https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial

Comment: Good link for basic Querydsl, but it doesn't cover Predicates/BooleanBuilder.